# How to make a column case sensitive in sql 2005 or 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to change the default collation based on a column? i want to make 1 column case sensitive but all the others not

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN` allows to change collation for a single column:

```
alter table Foo alter column Bar ntext collate Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

(collation might be incorrect)

Comment: A note about collation: I've had to write way too many COLLATE statements as a result of a source table being Latin1_General_CS_AS and one being Latin1_General_CI_AI.  This really only applies if you use SSIS to move data around, or at least, that's the only spot I've ever hit an issue in.

Answer (score 3):

I don't specifically know SQL Server, but the generally accepted DBMS practice (for compatibility) would be to either:

- put insert and update triggers on the table so that they're stored in the case you want.
- use generated columns to store another copy of the column in the case you want.

There may be a faster way to do it in SQL Server but you should be careful of solutions that push workload into the SELECT statements - they never scale well. It's almost always better doing this as part of inserts and updates since that's the only time data changes - doing it that way minimizes the extra workload.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is yes, already stated above by [Anton Gogolev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60188/anton-gogolev).

Additional Info:

Here is a how you can find list of Collation supported by your SQL Server based on its version.

```
select name, 
       COLLATIONPROPERTY(name, 'CodePage') as Code_Page, 
       description
from   sys.fn_HelpCollations()
```

[what is the meaning of Kanatype Sensitive KS and width sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489257/what-is-the-meaning-of-kanatype-sensitive-ks-and-width-sensitive)