# How to sort the Japanese Character in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to sort the following Japanese Character in Sql Server,

```
賃貸人側連絡先 (Lessor side contact)
解約連絡先 (Termination contacts)
賃借人側連絡先 (Lessee side contact)
更新連絡先 (Update contact)
```

above `order(1,3,2,4)`

But, Actual order is ,(ie. output that i want)

```
賃貸人側連絡先 (Lessor side contact)
賃借人側連絡先 (Lessee side contact)
解約連絡先 (Termination contacts)
更新連絡先 (Update contact)
```

above `order(1,2,3,4)`

I tried like this,

```
select * from test order by Test `COLLATE Japanese_CS_AS_KS`
```

but order of result like (3,4,2,1)

Comment: tried using `Japanese_Unicode_CI_AS` Collation or tried for `Chinese_PRC_CI_AS collation`..

Comment: I believe you are actually going to have to store a "sorting name" column where you put the reading in either hiragana or katakana, and sort by this instead. I do not think kanji by itself is inherently sortable by anything other than radical or stroke count.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at Windows [Japanese collations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188046.aspx) rather then your SQL collations (SQL Server supports both), by trial and error, this works

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (id int, SomeString nvarchar(100));
INSERT @t VALUES
(1, N'賃貸人側連絡先'),
(3, N'解約連絡先'),
(2, N'賃借人側連絡先'),
(4, N'更新連絡先');

select * from @t order by SomeString COLLATE Japanese_Bushu_Kakusu_100_CS_AS_KS desc
```

Not sure why you need DESC though. Also note `Japanese_XJIS_100_CS_AS_KS` does not work

Comment: here, what is need of "DESC"? without DESC, it showing in Descending order.Why it Showing like this

Answer (score 1):

The collation code has 3 particles at the end:

- CS - case sensitive
- AS - accent sensitive
- KS - kanatype sensitive which is smth Japanese related (discussed in
  this [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489257/what-is-the-meaning-of-kanatype-sensitive-ks-and-width-sensitive))

If you want a collation that is case insensitive- change CS to CI. So perhaps a different combination of sensitivities is required.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @gbn's answer

- 賃 has Radical-Stroke Count 154.6
- 解 has 148.6
- 更 has 73.3

So the question should rather be, why do YOU want descending order?

Comment: If i use "order by test COLLATE Japanese_Bushu_Kakusu_100_CS_AS_KS desc", it showing in descending order...i want display in Ascending order without using DESC..

Comment: @Vino: I use DESC to sort it how you want in the question. When I don't use DESC (=ASC) it gives reverse order to what you ask. Therefore, you are asking for descending order.. I think this is what devio's information explains

Comment: I think because he wants fonetic order, using that COLLATE DESC works almost 100% whith the text (but with that text of example only), to work as wanted it will need more complex study.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be creative. Your text contains Kanji, not only Hiragana or Katakana. It is possible to do order by Unicode value, but some times, you want the Kanji 更 be the firs,but not happens because combination with more Kanjis changes fonetic sounds, sometimes not the order you want... well some COLLATE can help but sometimes not that you want. In your case 更 readeble as "sa...", but 更新 is "kos.." That suggestion COLLATE Japanese_Bushu_Kakusu_100_CS_AS_KS seams to work well... but with other words isn't the solution yet. The problem maybe needs more advanced troubleshooting.

賃貸人側連絡先 "chintai hito gawa renraku saki"
賃借人側連絡先  "chinshaku hito gawa renraku saki"
解約連絡先 "kaiyaku renraku saki"
更新連絡先 "koshin renraku saki"